# Why do we not get the ordered sequence in HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

I am using the `HashSet` for adding the elements and retrieving them, I know that I will not retrieve the data in sequence in which I added them, but I want to know the exact reason why Is it happeing?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

 public class HS {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         HashSet h=new HashSet();
         h.add("Mayank");
         h.add("Mayank");

         h.add("Vashist");
         h.add("Dinesh");

         h.add("Vashist");

         Iterator itr=h.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(itr.next());
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just the contract for a `Set` in java, from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29)

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set.
>   The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee). So an implementation of `Set` isn't required to maintain any order in the values.

In order to return values in order the `Set` needs to maintain the order. This has costs for speed and space.

A [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) maintains insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

Because in HashSet there is a hash value calculated for each object and this hash value determines the array index of the particular object in the container. So the order of inserted elements are naturally not preserved.
This allows for accessing desired elements with O(1) complexity but it costs a lot of memory.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 3):

HashSet does not preserve the element addition order. First it computes the object hash code that should stay constant but is difficult to predict, and then uses it to select a bucket that is a list of objects that have had the same bucket selected. As an `Iterator` just iterates over all buckets, the iteration order is largely unpredictable.

Use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead if you need to preserve the order. However `LinkedHashSet` maintains an additional linked list so needs more resources.

Answer (score 2):

A `HashSet` uses what is referred to as a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to store items.

A hash table is made up of several "slots" into which your items are put.  Deciding what slot to put an item into is determined by that item's hash code which generally has no relationship to the natural ordering of the item.

A `TreeSet`, on the other hand, stores items based on their natural ordering which allows an in-order traversal of its contents.  This order will be based on the natural ordering of the objects and not the order in which they were inserted.  Another difference between a `TreeSet` and `HashSet` is that a `HashSet` provides O(1) lookup, insertion and removal where as a `TreeSet` provides `O(log(n))` lookup, insertion and removal.

A [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) maintains insertion order of items by constructing links between the elements as they are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation:

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over time. [...] The iterators returned
>   by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified
>   at any time after the iterator is created

Answer (score 0):

Here is ordered version:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

 public class HS {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         Set<String> h=Collections.synchronizedSet(new LinkedHashSet<String>());
         h.add("Mayank");
         h.add("Mayank");

         h.add("Vashist");
         h.add("Dinesh");

         h.add("Vashist");

         Iterator<String> itr=h.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(itr.next());
         }
     }
 }
```